# Unable to commit after removing a file from CVS using Tortoise CVS

Tags: cvs, tortoisecvs

I accidentally checked in a large binary file into CVS.  Now in trying to remove it, I get following error -

```
(x86)\CVSNT\cvs.exe" -q -z9 commit -M  vsim.wlf
CVSROOT=:sspi:swbuild1:\hardware

Removing vsim.wlf;
cvs server: C:\Windows\TEMP\cvsF1D.tmp: Invalid argument
cvs [server aborted]: error diffing vsim.wlf
cvs commit: Committed on the Free edition of March Hare Software CVSNT Client
           Upgrade to CVS Suite for more features and support:
           http://march-hare.com/cvsnt/
```

How do I work around this problem using a cvs client?  Is there a way to force CVS client to remove the file without diff'ing it?

Answer (score 2):

You can delete it directly from the CVS server. I had a similar problem where someone had checked in a file larger than 1GB; CVS would complain about memory allocation problems when trying to check out the file or attempting to delete it. We had to manually remove it from the server.

Comment: Thank you.  I was hoping for a cluent based solution.  It should be possible?  I am guessing.  Also clarified the question to indicate "using a client".